# Moderator nominations

Tags: discussion, moderators, top-7

One of the [seven beta questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) is deciding who the moderators should be

Some SE sites seem to start the moderator nominations [too early](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211/moderator-nominations), while others [forget about it completely](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153/moderator-nominations). Robert Cartaino's [blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) about this says he chooses provisional moderators

> starting about seven days into the public Beta

I figure a couple days into public beta is about the right time for us to start discussing it, so I'll post the standard nomination question

I plagiarized this almost verbatim from [Robert's post](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153/moderator-nominations) on another SE meta, since it seems to be the most complete of all the ones I looked at and I don't think he'll mind. I did change references to "we" to "the SE team" to try and avoid confusion

---

**Here are some basic guidelines:**

- Use this thread. Each nomination should be a separate answer. Link the name to the user's profile so we can see their activity.
- The nominee should indicate their acceptance by commenting on (or indeed editing) the answer.
- Self nominations are okay.
- Vote on users you feel will make **[good Moderator candidates](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)**. **Please be civil and respectful.**

We are looking for members who are deeply engaged in the community development; members who:

- Are currently a registered user in good standing.
- Have a reasonably high reputation score to indicate active, consistent participation.
- Exhibit patience and fairness at all times in their questions, answers, and comments.
- Lead by example, showing respect for their fellow community members in everything they write.
- Want the responsibility. Moderators volunteer a lot of time and work. Its can be hugely rewarding experience but it isn't always a popularity contest.

Bonus points for:

- Being the site proposer or heavily involved in the proposal process.
- Members who referred a lot of followers/committers on Area 51.
- Members with participation in *both* meta and the parent site (i.e. interest in both community building and expertise in the field).

These users will be contacted and three of them will be selected to act as Moderators until the formal elections.

They will:

- Have access to the tools to perform the duties of Moderation
- Have access to a special chat room where they will collectively work through the challenges of moderation and community self-policing with the Stack Exchange team
- Drive the process of selecting the site's attributes (domain names, design issues, the FAQ, etc.)
- Help get publicity for their sites and organize their communities

Basically, **they will have the ear of the Stack Exchange team for anything they can do to help this site succeed.** They will act as a liaison — a job that "links" Stack Overflow with this community.

Moderators solve a basic scalability problem. The SE team can't be in each site, identifying the issues and helping each community grow. That's where Moderators come in; they make sure communities are enabled to solve these problems where they can and elicit help when necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pro tem moderator announcement is [here](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85/moderator-pro-tem-announcement). We'll have a new thread when the elections for more permanent moderators start

Answer (score 7):

As nominations are rather lacking and we're supposed to have ["about three"](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) moderators, I'll nominate myself.

I've been fairly active here since the beta began, both on the parent site and meta:

[Unix flair http://mrozekma.com/so-flair.php?site=unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/73/michael-mrozek)

I've edited questions to cleanup formatting where I see it, but this site has had unusually high-quality posts, so there hasn't been much need of editing, closing, flagging, or actual moderator involvement yet.

SO, on the other hand, does regularly need that sort of thing. I'm very active there as well, and spend a majority of my time there these days on pseudo-mod activities: fixing posts by new users, retagging, going through spam/offensive flags, and checking active [un]close/[un]delete votes. I'm also fairly active on the main SO meta:

[SO flair http://mrozekma.com/so-flair.php?site=so](https://stackoverflow.com/users/309308/michael-mrozek)
[MSO flair http://mrozekma.com/so-flair.php?site=mso](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/145982/michael-mrozek)

I generally enjoy cleaning up existing posts as much as writing new answers, so moderator tools seem a decent extension of that

Comment: outside the tackiness of nominating yourself... I'll +1 for good answers a pretty high score already and having kept your nose clean.

Comment: My impression of Michael Mrozek from SO (where I'm also quite active) is very positive.  (IMHO, FWIW, YMMV, IANAL, etc.)

Comment: @xenoterracide: There's nothing "tacky" about expressing an interest in helping out (i.e. nominating yourself). It's recommended and actually quite helpful. Thanks @Michael!

Answer (score 4):

Nomination for [xenoterracide](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/29/xenoterracide)

I suppose I might as well put my name in the hat, seeing as how Robert Cartaino sent me an email asking if I was willing to be a temporary moderator, I said yes.

Comment: Oh, wow; for some reason I thought you were already nominated. Well, upvote for you, although I suspect it's immaterial since (as you said) I think he's already doing/done with the selection

Answer (score 3):

<sub>(Split from [this multi-suggestion post](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52/moderator-nominations/60#60))</sub>

Miguel de Icaza nominated [Warren Young](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/138/warren-young):

[image: Unix Flair]
[image: SO Flair]

Answer (score 1):

Good idea!

I nominate [Miguel de Icaza](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/228/miguel-de-icaza), but I have no idea if wants the responsibility.

He has been heavily involved in promoting unix.stackexchange, and probably had the biggest impact on its success in Area 51.  Since then he has continued his commitment to *nix by asking a bunch of questions during the private beta, and providing a ton of awesome answers.

Comment: I know nothing about this process but it concerns me that he asked one of the questions that was [voted closed offtopic](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/519/where-to-start-to-learn-opengl-closed) sure not everyone is perfect but that particular question seems so obviously offtopic here... If he can't make sense of stuff like that should he be a moderator? this is in all due respect of course.

Comment: @xeno If he had a history of off-topic posts I'd be concerned, but a one-time mistake early in the beta doesn't worry me, and his questions on the other sites seem entirely on-topic. If you know of him outside of this SE site, you know he's quite aware of what Linux is :). Also, referring 273 users, including the current top user, is rather impressive. (On an unrelated note, I'm not sure if he's seen this thread yet, so I pinged him on Twitter so we can make sure he actually wants to be a mod)

Comment: @Michael Good answers does not a good moderator make. The ability to recognize ontopic vs offtopic is much more important. But I'm not saying no, I'm just pointing at an instance where, imo, he lacked the judgement. I also notice that he didn't fully read this post when replying to it (one person per answer).

Comment: @xeno Yeah, that part (and not coming back to fix it yet) concerns me more

Answer (score 1):

<sub>(Split from [this multi-suggestion post](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52/moderator-nominations/60#60))</sub>

Miguel de Icaza nominated [Sandy](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/85/sandy):

[image: Unix Flair]
[image: SU Flair]

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me how much work this entails.  I'd be happy to help as long as it's not taking more than 20 minutes or so a day.

Comment: @Sandy I'm sure it varies from site to site, but I think the main mod task is going to be handling posts flagged for mod attention, and I can't imagine that will be a lot with our ~100-150 active users

Comment: Maybe we'll end up with thousands and thousands of active users!

Comment: Maybe we'll need more than three moderators.  I certainly hope so, eventually.

Comment: Sandy has been at least somewhat active on meta, which I approve of for moderator.

Comment: @David Probably, but we can always elect more; SO has done it a few times. And these are just pro tem moderators, which is another reason (@Sandy) not to be worried about the workload; it's very temporary

Answer (score 0):

Hello,

Thanks for nominating me!    I have had a great time on the launch of Unix.StackExchange and would like to remain involved.   I would like to also nominate all the other great posters that have been answering questions and have fostered both a friendly environment in this stack exchange as driven the discussion forward.

You have seen their comments:

- [Warren Young](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52/moderator-nominations/61#61)
- [Michael Mrozek](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52/moderator-nominations/57#57)
- [jacksonh](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52/moderator-nominations/62#62)
- [Sandy](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52/moderator-nominations/63#63)

<sub>(links go to individual posts for each nomination)</sub>

There are many others of course, but these fellow StackExchangers have done a great job keeping the ball rolling.

Comment: It'd be better if you post the nominations separately; we need a way to vote on each person individually. You can skip me since I [self-nominated](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52/moderator-nominations/57#57), but I appreciate it :)

Comment: I split the post into separate nominations, since it should probably happen sooner rather than later, and downvoted this so it'll be at the bottom of the list

Comment: Maybe you should delete this post for clarity, now that you've split this topic into multiple posts.

Answer (score 0):

<sub>(Split from [this multi-suggestion post](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52/moderator-nominations/60#60))</sub>

Miguel de Icaza nominated [jacksonh](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/users/45/jacksonh):

[image: Unix Flair]

Comment: I can't vote on this post (since I posted it while splitting Miguel's post), but jacksonh hasn't been on the main site in a week and meta in two weeks, so he's probably not interested

Comment: And then someone upvoted his nomination and downvoted all the others. That's....sporting

Answer (score 0):

Nomination for [xenoterracide](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/29/xenoterracide)

Comment: Duplicate of [this one](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52/moderator-nominations/82#82)